# How can I run supervisor?

Tags: command-line, python

I want to use supervisor to restart my python script:

/home/username/prog/test.py

```
import time
while True:
    print('I am alive.')
    time.sleep(1)
```

My config file:

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/testapp.conf

```
[program:testapp]
command=/usr/bin/python3 /home/username/prog/test.py > output.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/username/prog/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/username/prog/long.out.log
```

But output.txt is empty..

All permisions is ok.

Comment: Please don't simply tell us 'all permissions are ok'. Post some output. Also, looking at a [simple tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) for supervisor online, you have to run the commands `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update` for your config file to be used. Did you do that? Also, judging by this line `stdout_logfile=/home/username/prog/long.out.log`, anything your script prints will be logged into that file, you don't have to do `> output`.